# Disposing State between the pages of tabbar

Tags: dart, flutter, stateful

i am developing an app and it contains a timer in it so it updates the state every second but when we change the pages some state error occurs

> This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code
>   calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
>
> E/flutter ( 5287): This error might indicate a memory leak if
>   setState() is being called because another object is retaining a
>   reference to this State object after it has been removed from the
>   tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this
>   object during dispose().

I really don't know how to and where to use dispose() methode

Example of the error 
[Example](https://tenor.com/view/gif-13279643)

So please help me with disposing the previous widget tree and rebuild it when we switch screens.

My Code is can be separated into two. One main page that contains all the stuff and Two timer part which triggers the setstate.

First Part:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Theme.dart' as Theme;
import '../Components/ropSayac.dart';
import '../Components/Stackvideostile.dart';

class Ropo extends StatefulWidget {
  final RopoState state = new RopoState();
  void update(bool exp) {
    state.change(exp);
  }

  RopoState createState() => state;
}

class RopoState extends State<Ropo> {
  bool videomounted, expired;
  int remday = 0, remhour = 0, remmin = 0, remsec = 0;

  void change(bool exp) {
    setState(() {
      this.expired = exp;
    });
  }

  Widget updatetimer(int rday, rhour, rmin, rsec) {
    setState(() {
      remday = rday;
      remhour = rhour;
      remmin = rmin;
      remsec = rsec;
    });
  }

  Widget sayac(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 40.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        child: new Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              "BU HAFTAKİ RÖPORTAJA",
              style: Theme.TextStyles.ropsayacc,
            ),
            new Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            new Text(
              "$remday : $remhour : $remmin : $remsec",
              style: Theme.TextStyles.ropsayaccint,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget konukyazi() {
    // BU HAFTAKİ KONUĞUMUZ
    return new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
          "BU HAFTAKİ",
          style: Theme.TextStyles.koseice,
        ),
        new Text(
          "KONUĞUMUZ",
          style: Theme.TextStyles.koseice,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget konuk(String ad, var img) {
    // Yuvarlak Şeklindeki Karakter Fotoğğğğğğrafı ve Çerçevesi
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 226.0,
                height: 226.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Theme.Colors.pagebackground),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 215.0,
                height: 215.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: new AssetImage(img),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            height: 12.0,
          ),
          new Text(
            ad,
            style: Theme.TextStyles.kosebas,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget updateexpired(bool expiredd) {
    setState(() {
      expired = expiredd;
    });
  }

  Widget didvideomounted() {
    if (expired == true) {
      return new Text("video");
    } else
      return new Container(
        width: 226.0,
        height: 226.0,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: new Border.all(
                width: 5.0, color: Theme.Colors.roportajheroborder)),
      );
  }

  Widget rendervideoorui() {
    if (expired == false) {
      return new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          konukyazi(),
          Container(
            height: 60.0,
          ),
          konuk("Ayşe Alan", "assets/ayseAlan.png"),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return new Text("Video Geldi :D");
      // return video
    }
  }

  Widget stackvideos() {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.Colors.tabbarbackground,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, bottom: 10.0),
      width: 358.0,
      height: 343.0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            // Üstteki bar
            width: 358.0,
            height: 46.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.Colors.stackvideostopbar,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                new BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 3.0,
                  offset: new Offset(0.0, 7.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            child: Center(
              child: new Text(
                "BENCE Bİ’ ÖNCEKİLERE DE GÖZ AT",
                style: Theme.TextStyles.stackvideotitle,
              ),
            ),
          ), //üstteki bar bitti

        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  List<String> lists = ["asdas", "adadsa"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.Colors.pagebackground,
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 37.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/k@3x.png",
             // fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                RopSayac(this),

                new Expanded(
                   child: CustomScrollView(
                     slivers: <Widget>[
                       SliverToBoxAdapter(
                         child: new Column(
                           children: <Widget>[
                             rendervideoorui(),
                             new Container(height: 40.0,),
                             stackvideos(),         
                           ],
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          //new Image.asset("name"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second Part:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Pages/ropor.dart';
import '../Theme.dart' as Theme;
import 'dart:async';

class RopComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}

class RopSayac extends StatefulWidget {
  RopoState parent;
  RopSayac(this.parent);
  _RopSayacState createState() => _RopSayacState(parent);
}

class _RopSayacState extends State<RopSayac> {
  RopoState parent;
  _RopSayacState(this.parent);
  int remday = 0, remhour = 0, remmin = 0, remsec = 0;
  bool expired = false;
  var _now = DateTime.now();
  var endpoint = DateTime.parse("2019-01-24 11:23:30");

  Timer _everySecond;
  final Ropo ropo = new Ropo();

  Widget sayac(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 40.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        child: new Row(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              "BU HAFTAKİ RÖPORTAJA",
              style: Theme.TextStyles.ropsayacc,
            ),
            new Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            new Text(
              "$remday : $remhour : $remmin : $remsec",
              style: Theme.TextStyles.ropsayaccint,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //  RopoState bilge = new RopoState();

    // eğer videonun çıkacağı tarihten öndeysek
    //sayacı başlat
    _everySecond = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      if (_now.isBefore(endpoint) == true ||
          _now.difference(endpoint).inSeconds == 0) {
        //     bilge.updateexpired(false);
        expired = false;
        if (this.parent.mounted) {
          this.parent.setState(() {
            this.parent.expired = false;
          });
        }

        //    debugPrint(_now.toString());

        _now = DateTime.now();
        var remai = endpoint.difference(_now);

        ///   bilge.updatetimer(int.parse(remai.inDays.toString()), int.parse(remai.inHours.toString()) % 24, int.parse(remai.inMinutes.toString()) % 60, int.parse(remai.inSeconds.toString()) % 60);

        if (this.mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _now = DateTime.now();
            var remai = endpoint.difference(_now);
            remday = int.parse(remai.inDays.toString());
            remhour = int.parse(remai.inHours.toString()) % 24;
            remmin = int.parse(remai.inMinutes.toString()) % 60;
            remsec = int.parse(remai.inSeconds.toString()) % 60;
          });
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint("expired");
        if (this.parent.mounted) {
          this.parent.setState(() {
            this.parent.expired = true;
          });
        }

        //  bilge.updateexpired(false);
      }
    });
  }

  // defines a timer

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: sayac(context),
    );
  }
}
```

Full Error Log:

```
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
I/flutter ( 5287): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5287): The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
I/flutter ( 5287): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3803 pos 12: '_state._widget ==
I/flutter ( 5287): null': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287):
I/flutter ( 5287): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 5287): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 5287): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 5287):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 5287):
I/flutter ( 5287): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5287): #2      new StatefulElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3803:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #3      StatefulWidget.createElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:795:38)
I/flutter ( 5287): #4      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2948:40)
I/flutter ( 5287): #5      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter ( 5287): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter ( 5287): #19     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #20     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #21     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #22     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:11)
I/flutter ( 5287): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #25     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter ( 5287): #26     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #27     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #28     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter ( 5287): #29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 5287): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #32     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1028:36)
I/flutter ( 5287): #33     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1013:20)
I/flutter ( 5287): #34     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2266:19)
I/flutter ( 5287): #35     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1006:11)
I/flutter ( 5287): #36     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:274:23)
I/flutter ( 5287): #37     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1730:58)
I/flutter ( 5287): #38     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:799:15)
I/flutter ( 5287): #39     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1730:13)
I/flutter ( 5287): #40     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:263:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #41     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutLeadingChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:372:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #42     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:184:31)
I/flutter ( 5287): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 5287): #44     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:405:13)
I/flutter ( 5287): #45     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1316:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): #46     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1234:20)
I/flutter ( 5287): #47     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1509:7)
I/flutter ( 5287): #48     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:768:18)
I/flutter ( 5287): #49     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:281:19)
I/flutter ( 5287): #50     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:677:13)
I/flutter ( 5287): #51     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #52     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 5287): #53     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 5287): #54     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter ( 5287): #55     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
I/flutter ( 5287): #56     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
I/flutter ( 5287): (elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
I/flutter ( 5287): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 235 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 235 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2270 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 2 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
E/flutter ( 5287): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 5287): setState() called after dispose(): RopoState#2b3f4(lifecycle state: defunct)
E/flutter ( 5287): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code
calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 5287): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 5287): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1103:9)
E/flutter ( 5287): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1129:6)
E/flutter ( 5287): #2      _RopSayacState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:aurorav10/Components/ropSayac.dart:111:23)
E/flutter ( 5287): #3      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
E/flutter ( 5287): #4      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
E/flutter ( 5287): #5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1008 pos 14: 'insertFirst || _childElements[index-1] != null': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 3 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1008 pos 14: 'insertFirst || _childElements[index-1] != null': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 43 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1008 pos 14: 'insertFirst || _childElements[index-1] != null': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 7 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1008 pos 14: 'insertFirst || _childElements[index-1] != null': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 235 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 235 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2270 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 4 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 6 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 9 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 58 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 5287): uid=10086(com.example.aurorav10) 1.ui identical 6 lines
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 16: 'indexOf(child) == index': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5287): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 1053 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, please trim your code down to what is absolutely necessary when you post a question. There's a lot of code there to parse through (especially as it isn't all in english). At the very least, clean up your comments etc...

But the issue at hand is that you're creating a timer in the initState() function of `_RopSayacState` but then never stopping it. As the error you included in your question explained, that will cause problems as when the widget is no longer in view, it is removed from the widget tree and therefore calling `setState` on it will cause an error.

To fix this, all you should have to do is cancel the timer when the widget is removed. The easiest way to do this is override the dispose method in `_RopSayacState`. That should look like this.

```
@override
void dispose() {
 _everySecond.cancel();
 super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry ı have serious problems about clean coding. Bit of advise would be precious.By the way, it solved the dispose error but i am still getting the same error when I change the page and come back to my timer page. I am posting the error log as a answer please look.